# Unexpected token: OR in batch

Tags: apex, batch

I am writing a batch and in the start method I am having this error "Unexpected token: OR in batch",
in my query. Can anyone please help me
Below is my piece of code. Thanks

***The error is here  query += ' OR Statut__c = \'Caduque\'';***

```
global class Batch_EnvoieMailContratPerdu implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
     String query = null;

    query = 'SELECT Id';
    query += ', Reference_proposition_commerciale__c, Statut__c';
    query += ', ContratPerdue__c';
    query += ' FROM Contrat__c';
    query += ' WHERE ContratPerdue__c = false';
    query += ' AND Reference_proposition_commerciale__c != null';
    query += ' AND Statut__c = \'Résilié\'';
    query += (' OR Statut__c = \'Caduque\'');

     System.debug(query);
     return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the parentheses inside the actual query; you can only have chains of AND or OR within a query without using them.

That means you can do:

```
... AND ... AND ...
```

Or:

```
... OR ... OR ...
```

But the language requires that if you want to mix AND and OR, you have to choose how they interact by parentheses:

```
... AND (... OR ...) AND ...
... OR (... AND ...) OR ...
```

You probably meant:

```
query = 'SELECT Id';
query += ', Reference_proposition_commerciale__c, Statut__c';
query += ', ContratPerdue__c';
query += ' FROM Contrat__c';
query += ' WHERE ContratPerdue__c = false';
query += ' AND Reference_proposition_commerciale__c != null';
query += ' AND (Statut__c = \'Résilié\'';
query += ' OR Statut__c = \'Caduque\')';
```

That said, this code is horribly inefficient, as you could simply write:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator(
     [SELECT Reference_proposition_commerciale__c, Statut__c, ContratPerdue__c
      FROM Contrat__c
      WHERE ContratPerdue__c = false AND
            Reference_proposition_commerciale__c != null AND
            Statut__c IN ('Résilié','Caduque')]);
```

See [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_conditionexpression.htm) in the manual for more information. Specifically:

> Client applications must specify parentheses when nesting operators. However, multiple operators of the same type do not need to be nested.

Comment: it works, thxss